# Debranding Odoo backend on AWS platform

Tags: odoo-8

I want to remove Odoo Names, Logo, Links and Title for the normal user.  I just want to debranding odoo on AWS ubuntu server.

It is done only using command line interface.

Can anyone help me with that?.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in through FileZilla and replace all the odoo logos with your own.
Its best if you have odoo installed on a desktop so you can search through all the file to find there locations. All the odoo images are .png and 1 .jpg. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of how it would look if you did it though FileZilla.

[image]